# How to change the working directory when running R scripts with Rscript.exe in Windows

Tags: r, batch-file, rscript

I want to execute an R script `myscript.R` by using Rscript.exe on a Windows machine. However, my default home folder is configured to be `\\\\<domain>/home/m/myname/Documents`. I've made a wrapper DOS batch script (`run.bat`) on the same folder where `myscript.R`resides (actually a folder in a pendrive) in order to make it the current working directory:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM This batch file is an interface to run R scripts from the command line

SET RSCRIPT="c:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe"

echo "Changing drive and directory to %~dp0"

pushd "%~dp0"

REM we change "\" to "/"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set f=%*
set "f=!f:\=/!"

%RSCRIPT% %f%

popd
```

I call the script by `run.bat "myscript.R" --dir ../AnotherFolder`

So far, so good. However, the problem is that the script needs to change the working folder to a folder one level up (`../AnotherFolder`) but the `setwd()` R function fails. By debugging, I can see that the problem is that `Rscript.exe` loads the script `myscript.R` while still having the default directory setup to the home folder.

The question is: how the heck I can make Rscript.exe to ignore the default home directory and take the script directory as the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found my own answer after scratching my head the whole day. I've modified the wrapper batch file and add an extra command line argument `--drive` to be processed by my R script:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM This batch file is an interface to run R scripts from the command line

SET RSCRIPT="c:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe"

echo "Changing drive and directory to %~dp0"

pushd "%~dp0"

REM we change "\" to "/"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set f=%*
set "f=!f:\=/!"

set P=%~dpnx1

%RSCRIPT% %f% --drive "%P:~0,2%"

popd
```

Then, my R script must execute `setwd(drive)` where `drive` contains the value passed through the `--drive` option (e.g. "F:") before executing a `setwd()` on a relative path to the current folder.